# SQL Server: Recursive trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, rollback

I have a table on which I have created a trigger on the column 'ENABLED', see below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_TESTS] 
ON [dbo].[TESTS] 
FOR UPDATE 
AS
    IF UPDATE([ENABLED]) 
      BEGIN 
         (...) 
      END
```

This trigger receives 1 or multiple rows depending on the case. All these rows always have dependencies, I mean, they have children, for example:

Table TESTS:

```
TEST_ID | PARENT_TEST_ID | ENABLED
  1            NULL          0
  3            NULL          0
  4            NULL          0
  5             1            0
  6             1            0
  7             4            0
  8             3            0
```

Trees:

```
     1          3      4
    / \         |      |
   /   \        |      |
  5     6       8      7
```

- Test 1 depends on tests 5 and 6
- Test 3 depends on test 8
- Test 4 depends on test 7

For each of those rows received, an update is done on ENABLED column in the following way:

- From top (parent) to bottom (children): If we receive a test parent to update to ENABLED=1 all its children and descendants will be tried to set to ENABLED=1 if possible. If a test cannot be set to ENABLED=1 it will maintain its old value, the one previous trigger was fired.
- From bottom to top: If all the children of a test figure as ENABLED=1 or can be switch to ENABLED=1, then test (parent) is set to ENABLED=1, otherwise, if any of the children of the test cannot switch to ENABLED=1, then test parent will maintain its value to ENABLED=0 (old value).

For example:

Taken into account above trees:

- if test 5 is ENABLED=1 and test 6 is ENABLED=0 and we receive an
  update on test 1 to be set to ENABLED=1, then both tests 5 and 6 will be tried to set to ENABLED=1, if it is not possible test 1 will be set to its old value ENABLED=0.
- if both test 5 and 6 can be switch to ENABLED=1 and we receive an
  update on test 1 to be set to ENABLED=1, then test 1 will be set to ENABLED=1.

So when we receive rows to update, to be set to ENABLED=1, we need to check their children and update them if possible, and consequently update the parent according to them.

This is an example, but a lot of dependencies can exist, so recursive is needed and will exist because updates on the same table on which trigger is fired will be needed.

So I have thought 2 alternatives:

- Using a recursive CTE
- Make trigger recursive

Both cases needs to update the same table on which trigger is fired so it is impossible to avoid recursion as far as I know.

What worries me is:

- The database performance. I do not know if firing recursion on the same
  table is a good practice or is there any other way to do it and avoid recursion in this scenario.
- The fact that multiple rows at the same time can be received in the trigger, it does not allow to use the command rollback, because I need to update the tests that are possible. If some tests cannot be updated, I cannot use rollback command only on them, rollback is applied to all the set of rows received, so If rollback is done, it will undo all, even tests that have been updated correctly.

Under this scenario, which is the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*If a test cannot be set to ENABLED=1*"? What's stopping you from setting the `enabled` to 1? As for your last paragraph, you can use an `instead of update` trigger, so that you don't have to rollback anything.

Comment: Triggers (while having their uses) are already something to be used with ***extreme caution*** (and recursive triggers more so): 1) they're much more difficult to reason about because they're _reactive_ 2) their effects are external to whatever you're doing (i.e you have to actively seek them out to even consider them) 3) they're a source of a common misconception and many people write buggy triggers by making the ***false assumption*** they fire once per row inserted/updated/deleted. (fortunately you seem aware of this) 4) multi-row update trigger are very difficult to write correctly.

Comment: Given my above comment, a recursive CTE would be my preferred choice. Difficult to be sure though as you've made the mistake of stating your requirements in terms of a _perceived solution_. Rather just stating your _actual requirements_. There may also be aspects of your problem space that could make other options contenders: e.g. if it's worthwhile to maintain a denormalised representation of the hierarchy in another table; then you could solve your problem by joining to a table that easily returns all children or all ancestors of a node in a tree.

Comment: Also, How is this question different then the other 3 questions you've asked in the past 2 days?

Comment: @ZoharPeled All goes to the same point, but I have splitted it in different parts to try to solve the problem I have. It is very difficult to explain here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled "If a test cannot be set to ENABLED=1" I mean when I try to set a test to ENABLED=1 if check some conditions. If all conditions are satisfied then ENABLED=1 can be set, otherwise, if any condition fails, ENABLED=0. Using "Instead of update" as I have read in many posts it is not recomended to use. Am I wrong?

Comment: Triggers are not that easy to write correctly, as @CraigYoung commented. However, this doesn't mean that they can't be a good choice, instead of triggers are sometimes the only reasonable choice you have. This seems like one of these cases.